# SQL query for nested min and max

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm not sure if the title is worded correctly. Basically I have data that looks like this:

```
A    B    C
1    10   0.6
1    11   0.6
1    12   1.0
1    13   1.0
2    5    0.6
2    4    0.6
```

I want to pick a row with the largest C value. If that results in a duplicate row, I'll pick the one with the lowest B value

So, i'm expecting

```
A    B    C
1    12   1.0
2    4    0.6
```

What's the proper sql query for this?

Answer (score 1):

Here's one approach using aggregation with subqueries:

```
select t1.a, min(t1.b) b, t2.c
from yourtable t1 
   join (select a, max(c) c
         from yourtable
         group by a) t2 on t1.a = t2.a and t1.c = t2.c
group by t1.a, t2.c
```

- [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/492ad9/1)

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
select t.*
from t
where (t.b, t.c) = (select t2.b, t2.c
                    from t t2
                    where t2.a = t.a
                    order by t2.c desc, t2.b asc
                    limit 1
                   );
```

[Here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/5b19c/1) is a SQL Fiddle.

What is nice about this version is that it has no aggregation and can take advantage of an index on `(a, c, b)`.

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT A, B, C
FROM [myTable]
ORDER BY C DESC, B ASC
LIMIT 1
```

Answer (score -1):

In sqlite, a simple one-liner would be:

```
select A, min(B), C from tableXXX group by C order by C desc;
```